# Strategy Pattern and context class

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Reading about the strategy design pattern, was thinking if it is possible to have two context.

Looking forward for opinions if the below code-design utilises the Strategy design pattern.

Or strategy design pattern forces us to have only one context meaning that the design below is incorrect.

```
public interface Algorithm {}
public class FirstAlgorithm implements Algorithm {}
public class SecondAlgorithm implements Algorithm {}


public interface Cryptography {}

public class DecryptionContext implements Cryptography {
    public DecryptionContext(Algorithm algorithm) {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }
}

public class EncryptionContext implements Cryptography {
public EncryptionContext(Algorithm algorithm) {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used strategy within `Algorithm`, but with your example it's a little bit forced since it's not mandatory to bound `Contructor` with `Algorithm`.
 It's just an basic example of how to use `Strategy`.

```
public interface Algorithm
{
     public String doOperation(...);
}
public class FirstAlgorithm implements Algorithm { ... decrypt ...}
public class SecondAlgorithm implements Algorithm { ... encrypt ...}


//public interface Cryptography {}
//another option is to implement Algorithm on both Enc/Dec - class,
//it's only of your design and purpose
public class DecryptionContext  {
    ...
    public DecryptionContext(Algorithm algorithm,String strEncrypt) 
    {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
        ...
    }
}

public class EncryptionContext  {
public EncryptionContext(Algorithm algorithm, String strDecrypt) {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
        ...
    }

}

class Main
{
   ...
   Algorithm ae = new SecondAlgorithm();
   EncryptionContext ec = new EncryptionContext(ae, "abc");
   //this op can be done even inside EncryptionContext ... but the purpose is understanding strategy 
   String res = ec.ae.doOperation(ec.strDecrypt); //abc -> efg
   //since only need input string could be rewrite as
   //String res = ae.doOperation(ec.strDecrypt)
   ae = new FirstAlgorithm();
   DecryptionContext dc = new DencryptionContext(ae, res);
   res = dc.ae.doOperation(dc.strEncrypt); //efg->abc
   
}
```

Comment: So having two classes for each algorithm, one for encryption and another for decryption.
Using as context the DecryptionContext and EncryptionContext class makes as use the Strategy pattern is that correct?

Comment: Yes. `ae.doOperation(string)` - will do either encrypt or decrypt depends of how `ae` it's set (`First or Second Alg`). This is Strategy.(do not have 2 separate-ops, just 1 which will do both depends of settings)

Comment: I will accept your answer, could you provide please as well a more advanced example of the strategy design pattern, if not here at least a link because you mentioned "It's just an basic example of how to use Strategy."

Comment: As tutorial there are plenty on internet, maybe this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm#:~:text=In%20Strategy%20pattern%2C%20a%20class,as%20per%20its%20strategy%20object.

Comment: As book there is one used to learn from, maybe you could find it : "Patterns in Java: A Catalog of Reusable Design Patterns Illustrated with UML, 2nd Edition, Volume 1 2nd Edition by Mark Grand". One of the best in my opinion related to ... Have fun with learning !

Answer (score 1):

Strategy Pattern aims to implement an algorithm in multiple ways without clients being aware of its details. In your example, `Encryption` and `Decryption` are two different contexts and thus they will do two different things. Assuming your client will use `Cryptography` interface, you need to define `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods. In this case, you force `EncryptionContext` class to implement `decrypt` and `DecryptionContext` class to implement `encrypt` methods which would not be correct. That is why, I do not think this design couples with Strategy Pattern.